# Builds occasionally display incorrect drawables even though images are hardcoded

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, android-app-bundle

Several colleagues have reported random images in places where hardcoded images are used. The application in question displays a list of tiles, with each tile containing a single image.

The number of tiles is determined by an API response that provides a list of unique IDs, one for each tile. The application contains a hardcoded map that maps certain IDs to local drawables:

**API response callback:**

```
override fun onResponse(response: Response<CommonSearchTermsQuery.Data>) {
    // ...
    responseData.me()?.member()?.commonSearchTerms()?.map {
        CommonSearchModel(
            title = it.displayName(),
            uid = it.uid(),
            baseUrlForWebView = it.baseUrl(),
            imageResource = CommonSearchModel.getIllustration(it.uid())
         )
    }
}
```

**Data class:**

```
data class CommonSearchModel(
    var title: String,
    var uid: String,
    var baseUrlForWebView: String,
    var imageResource: Int
) {
    companion object {

        val mapping = mapOf<String, Int>(
            "{some ID}" to R.drawable.find_care_primary_care,
            "..." to R.drawable.find_care_obgyn,
            "..." to R.drawable.find_care_dermatology,
            "..." to R.drawable.find_care_pediatrics,
            "..." to R.drawable.find_care_urgent_care,
            "..." to R.drawable.find_care_psychiatry
        )
        @JvmStatic
        fun getIllustration(uid: String): Int {
            return mapping[uid] ?: R.drawable.primary_care
        }
    }
}
```

The list adapter is quite simple:

```
class CommonSearchesAdapter(
    var data: List<CommonSearchModel>,
    var listener: CommonSearchSelectionListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CommonSearchesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_common_search, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        with (data[position]) {
            // ...
            holder.itemView.illustration.setImageResource(imageResource)
            // ...
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Bizarrely, some individuals are reporting that random images from the application's drawable folder are rendering instead of the correct images as defined by the map.

This issue has not been reproducible by a QA team. The application is distributed via Android App Bundles, therefore Google signs and generates the builds. Only a few individuals have experienced the issue.

Comment: Do you cache or store responses in some way that'd let them live through app update and leak resource id? Perhaps you should keep your illustration ID in data class and only resolve it during viewholder binding.

Comment: @Pawel Yes! The API response is transformed into a list of `CommonSearchModel` objects and immediately serialized and stored in Shared Preferences. The function that retrieves the list of `CommonSearchModel` objects first checks Shared Preferences before performing the API call. Is that the problem? Do resource identifiers change when the app is updated?

Comment: Yeah resource IDs might get shuffled between builds, its best to just never save them in persistent storage and instead keep your own keys that will remain stable.